# jsdoc two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I have an array of array of string and I can't figure out how to document that with JSDoc.

```
/**
@class
*/
function PostbackList() {
    /**
    @type {int}
    @default
    */
    this.TypeID = 0;
    /**
    @type {PostbackList.Field[]}
    */
    this.Fields = new Array();
    /**

    !! Issue here !!


    @type {string[][]}
    */
    this.Values = null;
}
```

Which results in errors.

> Invalid type expression "string[][]": Expected "!", "?" or "|" but "["
>   found.

And I don't know if I should put `?` in front of the type to indicate it can be null.

Comment: I just tried mixing different syntaxes together and '@type {Array.<string[]>}' works. But if there's a way to just use '[]' it'll be nice to know.

Comment: Maybe make a function that doesn't have such a complicated API :P

Comment: Are two dimensional arrays being deprecated for best practice? O_o

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to what the current maintainer of jsdoc says in this [issue report](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/705), as we speak jsdoc 3 cannot handle declaring multidimensional arrays by adding square brackets. You can do it like you did with `Array.<string[]>`, or with `Array.<Array.<string>>`.

According to the issue report, version 3.3.0 will allow the notation you wanted to use.

Answer (score 6):

[Louis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25609755/3330861) answer is valid, but the maintainer [updated the repository](https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/705#issuecomment-65922137) and now also the code you provided is valid:

```
@type {string[][]}
```