# Define a typedef of an array

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

My function accepts an array (rows) of array (columns) containing data (cell value), e.g.

```js
table([
    ['A0', 'B0', 'C0'],
    ['A1', 'B1', 'C1'],
    ['A2', 'B2', 'C2'],
]);
```

How to describe the parameter value of the `table` function?

```js
/**
 * @typedef column
 */

/**
 * @param {column[]} rows
 */
table = (rows) => {};
```

I cannot find documentation how to describe that `column` `@typedef` is an array of string values.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/q/25602978/1595451

Answer (score 2):

I misread the [`@typedef` documentation](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-typedef.html). `@typdef` syntax allows defining `type` in addition to the `namepath`:

```js
@typedef [<type>] <namepath>
```

Therefore, my example would read:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {String[]} column
 */

/**
 * @param {column[]} rows
 */
table = (rows) => {};
```